# disabling the cmd close button by batch command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

im kinda new to the batch scripting.i had a problem recently about how to disable the close button of the cmd while the batch file is running.i saw some posts about how to overcome this.but the things stated there was out of my reach..if any1 could point me to a correct direction, it would be really great. it would be really preferred if sum1 can tell me how to do what i mentioned before inside my batch file.so when i use it in some other pc the effect would still be there...

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

You could hide the execution of the batch file by using a VBScript

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("yourbatchfile.bat"), 0, True
```

That would hide it from the user, but it wouldn't stop them from killing it in task manager.

What you're asking can't really be done.

Comment: Thanks @Bali c ...i would try it in VB..:)

Answer (score 2):

You could create an executable that disables the [X] button for all processes named "cmd", and run that executable the first line of your batch file.

Here is a c# program that does just that:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Remove__X__Button_from_another_process
{

class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uPosition, uint uFlags);

    const uint SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
    const uint MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Console.Write("Please enter process name:"); // "cmd"
        //String process_name = Console.ReadLine();

        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd");
        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            IntPtr pFoundWindow = p.MainWindowHandle;

            IntPtr nSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(pFoundWindow, false);
            if (nSysMenu != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                if (DeleteMenu(nSysMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND))
                {

                }
            }
        }
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `name.ps1` file in batch folder

```
$code = @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CloseButtonToggle {

 internal static class WinAPI {
   [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
   internal static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
   internal static extern bool DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu,
                          uint uPosition, uint uFlags);

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
   internal static extern bool DrawMenuBar(IntPtr hWnd);

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   internal static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd,
              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool bRevert);

   const uint SC_CLOSE     = 0xf060;
   const uint MF_BYCOMMAND = 0;

   internal static void ChangeCurrentState(bool state) {
     IntPtr hMenu = GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), state);
     DeleteMenu(hMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
     DrawMenuBar(GetConsoleWindow());
   }
 }

 public static class Status {
   public static void Disable() {
     WinAPI.ChangeCurrentState(false); //its 'true' if need to enable
   }
 }
}
'@

Add-Type $code
[CloseButtonToggle.Status]::Disable()
```

Add to batch

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File name.ps1
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19643299/17061201)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).