# Hide title bar in powershell

Tags: powershell

In a Powershell environment, is it possible to hide the title bar or at least remove the close button?

I have some scripts that I'd prefer the user not "poke" at while they're running.   I've considered running the script as hidden, but then the system will look like it's stuck for a minute or completely done when things are actually still going on under the covers.

Comment: Hmm, interesting question. I don't know of any way to achieve this functionality. Not that this answers your question, but the IMO best way to get users not to poke at stuff like this is to give them some feedback to assure them that the script hasn't stalled or something. Look up some implementations for progress bars in PowerShell, there's tons of examples out there. Otherwise you can just output things every couple of seconds.

Comment: If you want to customize the window, you'll probably need to write your own [host](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/10/19/the-shell-vs-the-host/) to run it in. Otherwise, provide feedback to the user in the form of progress bars and/or status messages so that they know it's not stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the close button of the Windows console with [this script at poshcode.org](http://poshcode.org/4059). However, the user can still close the console from the taskbar, and it doesn't work on console replacements such as ConEmu.

```
$code = @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CloseButtonToggle {

 internal static class WinAPI {
   [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
   internal static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
   internal static extern bool DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu,
                          uint uPosition, uint uFlags);

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
   internal static extern bool DrawMenuBar(IntPtr hWnd);

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   internal static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd,
              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool bRevert);

   const uint SC_CLOSE     = 0xf060;
   const uint MF_BYCOMMAND = 0;

   internal static void ChangeCurrentState(bool state) {
     IntPtr hMenu = GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), state);
     DeleteMenu(hMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
     DrawMenuBar(GetConsoleWindow());
   }
 }

 public static class Status {
   public static void Disable() {
     WinAPI.ChangeCurrentState(false); //its 'true' if need to enable
   }
 }
}
'@

Add-Type $code
[CloseButtonToggle.Status]::Disable()
```

Answer (score 2):

The only option that comes to mind is to hide the window that's running the script, then add this to your script:

```
start-process powershell.exe -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command "&{get-content c:\temp\log.txt -Wait}"'
```

and re-direct your script output to that file.  They'll be able to see the script ouput in that window, but nothing they do in that window will have any effect on the script.  At the end of the script, delete the log file and the log window will close.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Windows Form in PowerShell, and hide the control box:

```
[Void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    $form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.ControlBox = $false
    $form.Text = "Test Form"
    $Button = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
```

Would look like:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm... should be selected as best answer. Thanks.