# How do I disable/hide command box in batch file prompt?

Tags: shell, batch-file, cmd

How do I disable/hide the command box in the command prompt window brought up by a batch file?
Also how to force window to stay on top?

Comment: @echo off will hide the command box.

Comment: No, that only hides the print out of executed commands (and not output either)

Comment: I think I saw somewhere that it would involve the attrib command? I'm not sure though and can't find it on the Internet.

Comment: What do you mean by "the command box"? The minimize/maximize/close buttons on the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't with regular command prompt.

The long answer is: you can with [3rd party applications](http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html) or with the help of scripting as described in this answer https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file on Superuser (which by the way is the correct place for this type of questions)

***Edit:***
After further comments, the OP clarified that he wants to disable the close/minimize buttons on command prompt window, not the actual window. This was answered here, and unfortunately you cannot:
[disabling the cmd close button by batch command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763134/disabling-the-cmd-close-button-by-batch-command)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable the minimize/maximize/close buttons on the command prompt window.

Also, you will not be able to make the window stay on top using only batch commands. You can find a third party utility that will do that.